# Using Template::Toolkit with array data from database

Tags: mysql, perl

I don't know why my script works when I declare arrays in my script, but doesn't work when I try to get array data from a database.

#### Perl

```
use Template;

my $template = Template->new;

if ( $info ) {

    my $select = $DBH->prepare("SELECT FOO, BAR, MOO FROM tble WHERE CONCAT(FOO, ', ', BAR, ', ', MOO) LIKE ?");
    $select->execute('%' . $info . '%');
    $names = $select->fetchall_arrayref();
    foreach $names ( @$names ) {
        ( $variable1, $variable2, $variable3 ) = @$names;
    }
}

my $templ = <<START_HTML;
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
+" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

[% FOREACH name IN list %]
    <li>
      <div class='inforno'>
        <img src='inforno'>
      </div>
      <div class='inforno'>
        <a href='#' class='inforno'>[% name %]</a>
      </div>
      <span class='inforno'>
        <a href='#' class='inforno'>Edit user</a>
      </span>
    </li>
    [% END %]

</body>
    </html>
    START_HTML

$template->process(\$templ, { list => \@$names })
        or die $template->error;
```

#### output

```
    ARRAY(0x2030674)
    ARRAY(0x2030634)
    ARRAY(0x2030618)
```

When I run I get that error. I want to get the array data from database.

Comment: Why do you assign `( $variable1, $variable2, $variable3 ) = @$names` without using those variables?

Answer (score 2):

fetchall_arrayref returns a reference to an array that has an element for each row returned by the query.  Those elements are references to arrays with an element per column.

You are missing code to loop over the rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird:

```
{ list => \@$names }
```

`$names` is a reference to an array. You deference it (`@$names`) and then take another reference to the dereferenced array (`\@$names`). You could get exactly the same result with:

```
{ list => $names }
```

But none of that solves your problem. You're calling `fetchall_arrayref()` and that returns an array reference where each element of the array is a reference to another array. In effect, it's a two-dimensional array. The outer array is for the rows returned from your database query and the inner arrays are for the individual fields in each row.

When you see a value like `ARRAY(0x2030674)`, you should realise that you're displaying an array reference and you need to do one more level of dereferencing.

Your template code needs to look something like this:

```
[% FOREACH row IN LIST -%]
<p>Start of new record:</p>
<ul>
[%   FOREACH field IN row -%]
  <li>[% field %]</li>
[%   END -%]
</ul>
[% END %]
```

**Update:** You say:

> When I run I get that error.

But there's no error there. It's not even a warning. It's just data that you didn't quite understand :-)